# Changing values in a column based on a match

Tags: python, pandas, iteration

I have a Pandas DataFrame which contains names of brazilians universities, but somethings I have these names in a short way or in a long way (for example, the Universidade Federal do Rio de Janeiro sometimes is identified as UFRJ).
The DataFrame look like this:

```
| college                                |
|----------------------------------------|
| Universidade Federal do Rio de Janeiro |
| UFRJ                                   |
| Universidade de Sao Paulo              |
| USP                                    |
| Catholic University of Minas Gerais    |
```

And I have another one which has in separate columns the short name and the long name of SOME (not all) of those universities. Which looks likes this:

```
| long_name                              | short_name |
|----------------------------------------|------------|
| Universidade Federal do Rio de Janeiro | UFRJ       |
| Universidade de Sao Paulo              | USP        |
```

What I want is: substitute all short names by long names, so in this context, the first dataframe would have the `college` column changed to this:

```
| college                                |
|----------------------------------------|
| Universidade Federal do Rio de Janeiro |
| Universidade Federal do Rio de Janeiro |
| Universidade de Sao Paulo              |
| Universidade de Sao Paulo              |
| Catholic University of Minas Gerais    | <--- note: this one does not have a match, so it stays the same
```

Is there a way to do that using pandas and numpy (or any other library)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with  replace by second `DataFrame`, if no match get missing values, so added [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df1['college'] = (df1['college'].map(df2.set_index('short_name')['long_name'])
                                .fillna(df1['college']))

print (df1)
                                  college
0  Universidade Federal do Rio de Janeiro
1  Universidade Federal do Rio de Janeiro
2               Universidade de Sao Paulo
3               Universidade de Sao Paulo
4     Catholic University of Minas Gerais
```

Comment: But 'long_name' and 'short_name' are in a different dataframe than 'college', does the answer still right? I think you're assuming they are in the same one, aren't you?

Comment: @JohnP.S. - oops, my typo, it is `df2.set_index('short_name')['long_name']`